# What are these two characters?

Tags: character-identification

I need a little help deciphering a document. There are two characters that I'm unsure about, and I would appreciate your expertise. The first one seems to be 鵬, with the 朋 written together, but I'm not entirely certain. The second character is a bit trickier. I've searched through several dictionaries, but I couldn't find an exact match. The closest I found was 逆 or 溯.

If any of you have any insights or suggestions, I would be grateful for your assistance. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]
[image]

They are both from this page, from a local gazetteer:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to 教育部異體字字典, the first one is a variant of “鵬”:

https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTA0NzM4

the second one “氵”+“屰”, maybe it’s not chinese, a cjkv compatible character?

edited

> 重脩永春州志序

> 樂山草木・四序皆春・鵬嶽樓臺・萬家環翠

> 溯戴雲之孕毓・青隨天馬西來

> 展大羽之屏藩・秀引雙魚東障

well, i would read this “un-unicoded” character as “溯”, roughly as “recall” (「溯」表示往前推想、回想)

mainly, 鵬嶽 —> 大鵬山, 戴雲 (山), 天馬 (山), 大羽 (峰) & 雙魚 (山); all are place name in 永春州

have fun :)

Comment: I think ⿰氵屰 may just be a variant of 㴑.

Comment: @Mou某, any web sites, or documentations to proof?

Comment: It should be a Chinese character of some sort, since it's part of a Chinese document. It's a local gazetteer from the 1700s. I have added the entire image in the top post.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 https://wikisource.org/wiki/User_talk:BabelStone "[陝西通志（清雍正刊乾隆補修本）卷75 folio 65a](https://iiif.lib.harvard.edu/manifests/view/drs:428495331$66i) L4, L5; [明實錄（中央研究院歷史語言研究所1962年刊本）神宗卷506 校勘記 folio 3 pp 2329](http://sillok.history.go.kr/imageViewer/?levelId=msilok_015_0110_5070) L2; variant of 㴑?" ---- I can't see it in BabelStone PUA ---- which most likely means it is an interchangeable variant unsuitable for encoding.

Comment: @Mou某, the un-unicoded “氵”+“屰” in 陝西通志 & 畿輔通志; is . . .; well, i would read it as “溯”. further, the 異體字字典 mentioned that 「㴑」為「溯」之異體, isn’t it more straightforward to treat  “氵”+“屰” as variant of “溯”? https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAyMjc4LTAwMQ